# I'm creating a global chat feature for my Xamarin forms application but for some reason the text doesn't show up on my UI

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When ever I look at my UI the elements function as expected but anything bound to my view model doesn't show up however the binds seem to be working.
This is my view XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Fate.Views.GlobalChatPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:GlobalChatPageViewModel"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Fate.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Fate.Converters"
             BackgroundColor="#242022">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:GlobalChatPageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBool" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="ConnectButton" Text="Connect" Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}" />
                <Button x:Name="DisconnectButton" Text="Disconnect" Command="{Binding DisconnectCommand}" />
                <Entry IsReadOnly="False" x:Name="namenameEntry" Text="{Binding Name}" Placeholder="Enter Namename" />
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="MessagesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" HasUnevenRows="true" SelectionMode="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding IsOwnMessage, Converter={StaticResource InverseBool}}">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <Frame x:Name="MessageFrame" CornerRadius="10" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference MessageLabel}, Path=Height}" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                                        <Label x:Name="MessageLabel" Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="{Binding IsOwnMessage}">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                    <Frame x:Name="MessageFrame2" CornerRadius="10" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference MessageLabel}, Path=Height}" Margin="0,0,0,20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Label x:Name="MessageLabel2" Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Entry IsReadOnly="False" x:Name="MessageEntry" Text="{Binding Message}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Button x:Name="SendButton" Text="Send" Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is my view model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Fate.ViewModels
{
    public class GlobalChatPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _name;
        private string _message;
        private ObservableCollection<string> _messages;
        private bool _isConnected;
        public bool _IsOwnMessage;
        public bool _IsSystemMessage;

        public bool IsSystemMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return _IsSystemMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                _IsSystemMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsOwnMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return _IsOwnMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                _IsOwnMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }
            set
            {
                _message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Messages
        {
            get
            {
                return _messages;
            }
            set
            {
                _messages = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get
            {
                return _isConnected;
            }
            set
            {
                _isConnected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private HubConnection hubConnection;

        public Command SendMessageCommand { get; }
        public Command ConnectCommand { get; }
        public Command DisconnectCommand { get; }

        public GlobalChatPageViewModel()
        {
            Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            SendMessageCommand = new Command(async () => { await SendMessage(Name, Message); });
            ConnectCommand = new Command(async () => await Connect());
            DisconnectCommand = new Command(async () => await Disconnect());

            IsConnected = false;

            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl($"https://placeholderlink/chatHub")
                .Build();

            hubConnection.On<string>("JoinChat", (user) =>
            {
                Messages.Add($"{user} has joined the chat");
                IsSystemMessage = true;
                IsOwnMessage = false;
            });

            hubConnection.On<string>("LeaveChat", (user) =>
            {
                Messages.Add($"{user} has left the chat");
                IsSystemMessage = true;
                IsOwnMessage = false;
            });

            hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
            {
                Messages.Add($"{user}: {message}");
                IsSystemMessage = false;
                if (Name == user)
                {
                    IsOwnMessage = true;
                }
            });


        }

        public async Task Connect()
        {
            if (IsConnected == false)
            {
                await hubConnection.StartAsync();
                await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("JoinChat", Name);

                IsConnected = true;
            }
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", user, message);
        }

        public async Task Disconnect()
        {
            if (IsConnected == true)
            {
                await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("LeaveChat", Name);
                await hubConnection.StopAsync();

                IsConnected = false;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my converter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Fate.Converters
{
    public class InverseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting for the text from each message to display on the page, on the left if its from someone else and on the right if its from the user but the text doesn't display at all. I've checked my binding context and I get intellisense and no build errors but it still doesn't display.

Comment: each Message is just a string, how do you track which user sent each message?  `IsOwnMessage` only has a single value for the entire VM, it should be a per-message value.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem 1

You're using [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings) by applying the `x:DataType` property. Therefore, you need to set the correct `x:DataType` also for any `DataTemplate` further down in the View hierarchy, because the binding context changes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Fate.Views.GlobalChatPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:GlobalChatPageViewModel"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Fate.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Fate.Converters"
             BackgroundColor="#242022">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:GlobalChatPageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBool" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="ConnectButton" Text="Connect" Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}" />
                <Button x:Name="DisconnectButton" Text="Disconnect" Command="{Binding DisconnectCommand}" />
                <Entry IsReadOnly="False" x:Name="namenameEntry" Text="{Binding Name}" Placeholder="Enter Namename" />
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="MessagesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" HasUnevenRows="true" SelectionMode="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate
                        x:DataType="YOUR_TYPE_HERE">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <!-- ... -->
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Entry IsReadOnly="False" x:Name="MessageEntry" Text="{Binding Message}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Button x:Name="SendButton" Text="Send" Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Where it says **YOUR_TYPE_HERE**, you need to specify the same type as the collection you're passing to the `ItemsSource`, in your case `string` (or the XAML equivalent of it, which would be `{x:Type x:String}`). You can also reset the binding to classic bindings by setting the type on the `DataTemplate`'s `x:DataType` to `{x:Null}`.

### Problem 2

In your `DataTemplate` you're binding to properties that don't exist in that context, because your `ListView` is populated with an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

If you want to bind to `Name` from your ViewModel, for example, you'll need to specify a relative binding:

```xml
<ViewCell>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
            <Label Text="{Binding Name, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:GlobalChatPageViewModel}}" />
            <!-- ... -->
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

### Alternative

A quick fix might be to simply remove the `x:DataType` on the `ContentPage`.

### Further observations

You're binding to `Name` multiple times. It's unclear how the two chat participants are managed and where each participant's name and the messages are coming from, especially since there is only a single `Name` property and a single `Messages` collection in your ViewModel.